# Replace strings in a dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a 200k rows dataframe with a character column named "departament_name", some of the values in this column contain a specific char: "?". For example: "GENERAL SAN MART?N", "
UNI?N", etc.
I want to replace those values using another 750k rows dataframe that cointains a column also named "departament_name", but the values in this column are correct. Following the example, it will be: "GENERAL SAN MARTIN", "UNION", and so on.

Can I do this automatically using pattern recognition withouth making a dictionary (there are several values with this problem).
My objetive is to have an unified dataset with the two dataframes and unique values for those problematics rows in "departament_name". I prefer tidyverse (mutate, stringr, etc) if possible.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `stringdist.*` joins from `fuzzjoin` package.

```
fuzzyjoin::stringdist_left_join(df1, df2, by = 'departament_name')

#  departament_name.x departament_name.y
#1 GENERAL SAN MART?N GENERAL SAN MARTIN
#2              UNI?N              UNION
```

Obviously, this works for the simple example you have shared but it might not  give you 100% correct result for all the entries in your actual data. You can tweak the parameters `max_dist` and `method` as per your data. See `?fuzzyjoin::stringdist_join` for more information about them.

**data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(departament_name = c("GENERAL SAN MART?N", "UNI?N"))
df2 <- data.frame(departament_name = c("GENERAL SAN MARTIN", "UNION"))
```

Comment: I think a need a full join to unify the dataframes. Another problem is that the dataframe give information about different time series (one from 2018~2019 the other from 2020~2021) so i must keep all data from the two of them (put one "under" another). Leftjoins are problematic in this cases.